# What should my cspack command be to package azure project

Tags: azure

I have tried so many different ways, please help.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
trunk/Portal/MYAPPLICATION.Cloud    (cloud project)
trunk/Portal/Portal/MYAPPLICATION.Portal    (web app)
```

My ServiceDefinition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="MYAPPLICATION.Cloud" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-05.1.7">
<WebRole name="MYAPPLICATION.Portal" enableNativeCodeExecution="true">
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" />
  <Setting name="DataConnectionString" />
  <Setting name="BaseUrl" />
  <Setting name="DatabaseConnectionString" />
  <Setting name="Environment" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
</Endpoints>
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
</Imports>
</WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

I call the cspack from code as a part of the build process on build server.

```
  csPackProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-06\bin\cspack.exe",
            Arguments = sb.ToString()
        };
```

So specifically, what should my arguements be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the following in the **trunk/Portal** folder:

```
cspack MYAPPLICATION.Cloud\ServiceDefinition.csdef /out:MYAPPLICATION.cspkg /role:MYAPPLICATION.Portal;Portal\MYAPPLICATION.Portal /sites:MYAPPLICATION.Portal;Web;C:\trunk\Portal\Portal\MYAPPLICATION.Portal
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx